# Getting LNK error 2019 in QT

Tags: c++, qt

I'm running the following simple code in QT (it requires openBR, but I've installed it). The project is named "openBRtest". This file is named openbrtestplugin.cpp:

```
//Playing Video
#include <openbr_plugin.h>

using namespace cv;

static void printTemplate(const br::Template &t)
{
    const QPoint firstEye = t.file.get<QPoint>("Affine_0");
    const QPoint secondEye = t.file.get<QPoint>("Affine_1");
    printf("%s eyes: (%d, %d) (%d, %d)\n", qPrintable(t.file.fileName()), firstEye.x(), firstEye.y(), secondEye.x(), secondEye.y());
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    br::Context::initialize(argc, argv);
    // Retrieve classes for enrolling and comparing templates using the FaceRecognition algorithm
    QSharedPointer<br::Transform> transform = br::Transform::fromAlgorithm("FaceRecognition");
    QSharedPointer<br::Distance> distance = br::Distance::fromAlgorithm("FaceRecognition");
    // Initialize templates
    br::Template queryA("../data/MEDS/img/S354-01-t10_01.jpg");
    br::Template queryB("../data/MEDS/img/S382-08-t10_01.jpg");
    br::Template target("../data/MEDS/img/S354-02-t10_01.jpg");
    // Enroll templates
    queryA >> *transform;
    queryB >> *transform;
    target >> *transform;
    printTemplate(queryA);
    printTemplate(queryB);
    printTemplate(target);
    // Compare templates
    float comparisonA = distance->compare(target, queryA);
    float comparisonB = distance->compare(target, queryB);
    // Scores range from 0 to 1 and represent match probability
    printf("Genuine match score: %.3f\n", comparisonA);
    printf("Impostor match score: %.3f\n", comparisonB);
    br::Context::finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the h file, openbrtestplugin.h:

```
#ifndef OPENBRTESTPLUGIN_H
#define OPENBRTESTPLUGIN_H

#include <QDesignerCustomWidgetInterface>

class openbrTestPlugin : public QObject, public QDesignerCustomWidgetInterface
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_INTERFACES(QDesignerCustomWidgetInterface)
#if QT_VERSION >= 0x050000
    Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID "org.qt-project.Qt.QDesignerCustomWidgetInterface")
#endif // QT_VERSION >= 0x050000

public:
    openbrTestPlugin(QObject *parent = 0);

    bool isContainer() const;
    bool isInitialized() const;
    QIcon icon() const;
    QString domXml() const;
    QString group() const;
    QString includeFile() const;
    QString name() const;
    QString toolTip() const;
    QString whatsThis() const;
    QWidget *createWidget(QWidget *parent);
    void initialize(QDesignerFormEditorInterface *core);

private:
    bool m_initialized;
};

#endif
```

And here is my pro file:

```
CONFIG      += plugin debug_and_release
TARGET      = $$qtLibraryTarget(openbrtestplugin)
TEMPLATE    = lib

HEADERS     = openbrtestplugin.h
SOURCES     = openbrtestplugin.cpp
RESOURCES   = icons.qrc
LIBS        += -L. 

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4) {
    QT += designer
} else {
    CONFIG += designer
}

target.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS]/designer
INSTALLS    += target

include(openbrtest.pri)

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../opencv-2.4.6.1/build-msvc2012/lib/ -lopencv_core246
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../opencv-2.4.6.1/build-msvc2012/lib/ -lopencv_core246d

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../opencv-2.4.6.1/build-msvc2012/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../opencv-2.4.6.1/build-msvc2012/include

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../opencv-2.4.6.1/build-msvc2012/lib/ -lopencv_highgui246
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../opencv-2.4.6.1/build-msvc2012/lib/ -lopencv_highgui246d
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../opencv-2.4.6.1/build-msvc2012/lib/ -lopencv_highgui246

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../opencv-2.4.6.1/build-msvc2012/include
INCLUDEPATH+= C:\opencv-2.4.6.1\include

INCLUDEPATH += C:\openbr\build-msvc2012\install\include
INCLUDEPATH += C:\openbr\build-msvc2012\install\include\openbr
INCLUDEPATH += C:\opencv-2.4.6.1\modules\core\include
DEPENDPATH += C:\openbr\build-msvc2012\install\lib



INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../openbr/build-msvc2012/install/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../openbr/build-msvc2012/install/include

LIBS += -lC:\openbr\build-msvc2012\install\lib\openbr
```

And I'm getting the following linker error:

```
moc_openbrtestplugin.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl openbrTestPlugin::openbrTestPlugin(class QObject *)" (??0openbrTestPlugin@@QEAA@PEAVQObject@@@Z) referenced in function qt_plugin_instance
```

I have no idea what can cause it. I added the necessary includes and libs in the pro file.

I'll be glad for some help as I'm quite stuck and have no idea how to solve it.

Thanks,
Gil.

Comment: Try to include the source for moc_openbrtestplugin.cpp here ... seems it requires some funny construct (class openbrTestPlugin, with a constructor taking in a QObject... possibly you will need to declare and define this class ... ) ... Also openbrtestplugin.h

Comment: @fritzone, openbrTestPlugin.cpp is the first file I copied to my question.

Comment: moc_openbrtestplugin.cpp, not openbrTestPlugin.cpp ... ie. the generated moc file

Comment: Sems you need to define the constructor: `openbrTestPlugin::openbrTestPlugin(QObject *parent)` in the CPP file